# libxml2 avoid xml version

Tags: c, libxml2

I'm working with a protocol based on XML, something like:

```
<Command Timestamp="0" ReceptionTimeStamp="0" Sender="P1" Receiver="P2"><GetData/></Command>
```

I can successfully parse these messages using xmlReadMemory and navigating through the tree. When trying to create my own messages I can create them successfully this way:

```
doc = xmlNewDoc(NULL);
node = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "Command");
xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, node);

xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "Timestamp", BAD_CAST "0");
xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "ReceptionTimestamp", BAD_CAST "0");
xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "Sender", BAD_CAST "P1");
xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "Receiver", BAD_CAST "P2");

xmlNewChild(node, NULL, BAD_CAST "GetData", NULL);
```

The problem comes when trying to get the correspondant string as I get the xml version in the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Command Timestamp="0" ReceptionTimeStamp="0" Sender="P1" Receiver="P2"><GetData/></Command>
```

Is there any way to avoid it ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, since the version is valid XML what is the reason for wanting to remove it?

Comment: I still have to try it, but at the moment I only wanted an equivalent string. I'm not sure if the other side will be expecting it.

Answer (score 3):

I have find a solution/workaround by using xmlNodeDump with the root node:

```
xmlBufferPtr buf = xmlBufferCreate();
int size = xmlNodeDump(buf, NULL, node, 0, 0);
printf ("%s\n", buf->content);
xmlBufferFree (buf);
```

Comment: This is how I do it as well, except that I don't create an `xmlDocument` for it, just the root `xmlNode` (and children) by itself.  Note that `xmlNodeDump()` returns the content length, so you could optionally pass that to `printf()` and not rely on a null terminator being present.

Comment: Nice! I have updated the code.

Regarding not relying on a null terminator, are you refering to this ?

    printf("%.*s", size, buf->content);

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.